# Facebook Fan count

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having some issues to put a simple Fan Count(likes) in my website. I use GRAPH API of facebook. But  now when I use $exec = curl_exec($ch);

```
function get_fb_data($page_id) {
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . urlencode($page_id));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    echo $exec = curl_exec($ch);

    return json_decode($exec);

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

And this is printing:

> {"error":{"message":"(#4) Application request limit
>   reached","type":"OAuthException","code":4}}

This mean that I use too many calls. BUT, How I do to fix that...

I am thinking just do a call every 10 minutes and store this String

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait and then call less often. Also add an access token to the calls. Calls without an access token is limited much more then with